# Unable to get MongoDatabase class in MongoDB.Driver 2.4.4 version

Tags: mongodb

I am migrating MongoDB.Driver 1.10.0.62 t0 MongoDB.Driver 2.4.4 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver/2.4.4

In my project (1.10.0.62) I am using MongoDatabase Class
But once I migrated to 2.4.4 , I'm getting compilation errors as this class is not present in 2.4.4 MongoDB.Driver.
How to resolve this? 
Is there any breaking changing document available from 1.10.0.62 to 2.4.4?

Comment: MongoSecurityException  class is present in 1.10.0.62 and missing in 2.4.4 , what is the equivalent class in 2.4.4 version ?